# regular languages section closure property

Tags: regular-language, sections, computation-theory

Let L be a language and R an infinite regular one. If L intersection R is a regular language, then L is a regular one too?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[regular]` and `[language]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[regular-language]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for informing me! I didn't know that. However, it doesn't seem that anybody knows the answer :/

Comment: It's the weekend, and your question has a pretty narrow audience.  Give it a once-over edit in about 18 hours and it might gain more attention.

Comment: Too narrow I guess! I am not sure what you mean by an once-over edit! What should I edit? Do you think that the problem I had with the tag class may be an issue and I should delete this post and post it again? Or something relevant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let L = {1^p: p is prime} and R = {1^(2n) : n belongs to N}.

[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663859/regular-languages-and-intersection/663862?noredirect=1#comment1396633_663862)